# jquery: calling functions recursively

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wanted to call onIdle() recursively. But when I run it, the function onIdle() is not defined. How can I call onIdle() inside onIdle()?

```
$(document).idle({
    onIdle: function(){
    
       console.log("number of active jQuery: " + jQuery.active);
    
       if (jQuery.active > 0) {
    
           // add set timeout
           setTimeout(wakeBrowser, 10);
    
           function wakeBrowser() {
               onIdle(); // onIdle is not defined
           }
    
          return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider creating the function outside the `idle(` call, and call it `onIdle` and then pass it to the idle call `idle(onIdle)`?

Comment: It's not *recursive* unless you are calling the function within the function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just name the function when you define it, then use that name to call it recursively:

```
$(document).idle({
    onIdle: function myIdleFunc(){
    
       console.log("number of active jQuery: " + jQuery.active);
    
       if (jQuery.active > 0) {
    
           // add set timeout
           setTimeout(wakeBrowser, 10);
    
           function wakeBrowser() {
               myIdleFunc();
           }
    
          return;
        }
    }
}
```